# How can I add extra option to Django ImageField directly?

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-models

I have simple model in django with an ImageField:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='albums')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/albums/')
    #...
```

I want to add multiple Images in admin. **How can I add extra option to let user to add multiple images?** I just saw few tutorials but they were all using ManyToManyField or ForeignKeyField which is doesn't fit in my case.

Comment: Why `ManyToMany` field does not fit your case?

Comment: I just don't want to use it, but it seems I have to.

Answer (score 0):

Add model for image with foreign key to `Album` model.
Then in add `inlines` in `AlbumModelAdmin`. See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin).